# When I create a database item it saves multiple times and returns 'no data received'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making one of my first rails apps from scratch and cannot figure out what is going on.  Whenever I try to create a new instance, it saves multiple instances of the item.  I am trying to make tasks, and each time I create a new instance it saves 7 times, and then gives me an error page saying no data received.  I tried adding a uniqueness validator for the model, but that would save the first instance then return me to root path.  This is what I have:

Task Controller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
def index
    @tasks = Task.all
end

def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    if @task.save
        redirect_to 'tasks'
    else
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end

private

    def task_params
       params.require(:task).permit(:title, :category, :difficulty)
    end

end
```

Here is the form I am using, perhaps that is the problem?

```
<div id='task_form'>
<%= form_for :task do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title%>

    <%= f.label :category %>
    <%= f.text_field :category%>

    <%= f.label :difficulty %>
    <%= f.text_field :difficulty%>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
 </div>
```

Thanks if anyone knows what this is or has experienced it before

Comment: That sounds like a very strange problem. Do you have the server log that covers these requests? Have you tried to step through the request using something like [pry-debugger](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger)? Have you tried monitoring the browser console for network activity? AJAX? Does the same happen when you create a Task through the console? Do you have any before/after filters on your controller (incl. `ApplicationController`)? Any other helpers which might be interfering? Is this a constant problem, or recently occurred, if so, did you install a gem, or change environment, etc.?

Comment: What does `redirect_to 'tasks'` do?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
#app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb
def new
   @task = Task.new
end

#app/views/tasks/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @task do |f| %>
```

--

**Problem**

I frankly don't know why you're getting multiple submits, but I can see one of the issues you have is you're using a `symbol` in place of an `instance variable`.

This wouldn't normally be an issue, but as you're experiencing these problems, I would certainly use an `instance variable` in the form. (if only to test).

This does several important things:

1. Using an `@instance var` creates an `ActiveRecord` object for your form
2. The use of an `ActiveRecord` object gives rails a definite structure for the object
3. By saving the object, Rails is able to populate the appropriate `attributes` etc

I would certainly try the above code, but there may be other issues at work here if your form is submitting *7* times.